# How to deal with assets outside vue compoents using vite

Tags: vue.js, vite, quasar-framework, pinia

how to deal with assets (images) outside componts ?
i know that vite will build the image and add it to builded dir if i use it inside the compoent in an img tag like this :src="some image url"

but what if the url is coming from pinia store for example. then what shoud i do in the pinia store file to insure the image will be builded and work on production (online)
i tried what i found on the vite docs "importing the images" but its only work localy but not on production

heres what it did

```js
/// this is a pinia store (just copied the state function for simplification )
/// on the top of the file i did import the images like this
import image_1 from 'src/assets/list_images/image_1.png'
import image_2 from 'src/assets/list_images/image_2.png'
state: () => ({
   section_types: [
     {
       id: 1,
       name: "Products list",
       have_screen: false,
       img: image_1,
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       name: "banners list",
       have_screen: false,
       img: image_2,
     }]
}),
```

now on the ui iam looping that list and doing this

```
<item v-for="item in mystore.section_types"
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <img :src="item.img" />
</item>
```

this work fine on developemnt but when building the images are not visible on the online version
also looking inside the assets folder on the builded dir there is no image from the two images (meaning not builded)
...
what iam doing wrong ?

Comment: Vite _should_ bundle any imported asset... Is there anything unusual about your project config?

Comment: iam using quasar cli (vite), so for me everthing in the quasar.config.js but nothing unusal there

Answer (score 0):

**Update: its working now**

conclusions:

A - theoretically from the point i imported the files like bellow it's worked

```js
import image_1 from 'src/assets/list_images/image_1.png'
import image_2 from 'src/assets/list_images/image_2.png'
```

B- i dident see fix results for two reasons
1- during debuging i was wating for somthing that will not going to happen (i was wating to see images files in the outputed assets folder as .png), vite dont do that for images.
2- the browser also didnt help becouse things worked after i did a hard refresh.

i dident now that quasar provide a serve command for builded filse (man i love quasar)
when i did quasar serve (on the builded dir) things worked (becose there was no chaching), thene upload the build files to server and doing hard refresh and voala